# IE not getting the right next element

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

Suppose I click `<div class="span10 -configGroup-title" >`

In IE the `$(this).parent().next().next()` gets back the `<img alt="arrow" src="../arrow_normal.png" class="-arrow" />`

In Chrome it gets the `<div id="seconddiv"/>`

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="span10 -configGroup-title" >
          <img alt="arrow" src="../arrow_normal.png" class="-arrow" />
          <img alt="arrow" src="../arrow_down.png" class="-arrow" style="display: none;" />
          <asp:Literal ID="ltGroupAttrName" runat="server" />
     </div>  
 </div>  
 <asp:ListView ID="lvProperties" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"  />
<div id="seconddiv"/>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code - your example has no `li` or `#second` elements.

Comment: This is related to the markup not jQuery.

Comment: What is the context in which `$(this)` refers to the `<div class="span10 ...">`?

Comment: What is `<div id="seconddiv">`? It doesn't show up in your code

Answer (score 0):

I imagine what is happening (though I can't be sure without seeing the full code and being able to test it) is that you are *actually* clicking on one of the children of `<div class="span10 -configGroup-title">` when you are trying to click on the `div` itself (which makes sense, since the two `img` tags will be on a higher topological level than the `div`).

You can try debugging this by inserting some code to display an identifying property of `$(this)`. That may illuminate what is going on for you.

Comment: i am actually clicking the <div class="span10 -configGroup-title" > itself..  what i dont understand is... in IE the parent().next().next().toggle() is toggling the <img alt="arrow" src="../arrow_normal.png" class="-arrow" />... i want the **<div id="seconddiv">** to be called just like in chrome, opera, firefox

Comment: No, I understand what you want. But *how* do you know that you're clicking the actual `DIV`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(this).parent(".row").siblings("#seconddiv");
```